# Proof of joint distribution of the order statistics for n=2

Tags: probability

**Theorem**
Let $X_{1},X_{2}$ be i.i.d. and continuous with the common pdf $f_{X}$. Then the vector of order statistics $(X_{(1)},X_{(2)})$ has joint pdf:
\begin{equation}
f(x_{1},x_{2})=2f_{X}(x_{1})f_{X}(x_{2}),
\end{equation}
for $-\infty<x_{1}\leq x_{2}<\infty$.

**Proof**
Let $x\leq y$ and consider the joint cdf of $(X_{(1)},X_{(2)})$:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
F(x,y)&=P(X_{(1)}\leq x,X_{(2)}\leq y)\\
&=P(X_{1}\leq y, X_{2}\leq y)-P(x<X_{1}\leq y,x<X_{2}\leq y).\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
(...)

What I can't seem to figure out, is how the last equality is derived. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$\{X_1\leqslant y, X_2 \leqslant y\} \\ =\{ X_1 \leqslant X_2,X_1 \leqslant x, X_2 \leqslant y\} \cup \{ X_1 > X_2,X_1 \leqslant y, X_2 \leqslant x \}\cup\{x < X_1 \leqslant y, x < X_2 \leqslant y\},$$

where the three sets on the RHS are disjoint, and

$$\{X_{(1)} \leqslant x, X_{(2)} \leqslant y \} = \{ X_1 \leqslant X_2,X_1 \leqslant x, X_2 \leqslant y\} \cup \{ X_1 > X_2,X_1 \leqslant y, X_2 \leqslant x \}$$

Thus,

$$P(X_1\leqslant y, X_2 \leqslant y) \\ =P( X_1 \leqslant X_2,X_1 \leqslant x, X_2 \leqslant y) + P( X_1 > X_2,X_1 \leqslant y, X_2 \leqslant x ) + P(x < X_1 \leqslant y, x < X_2 \leqslant y)\\ = P(X_{(1)} \leqslant x, X_{(2)} \leqslant y) + P(x < X_1 \leqslant y, x < X_2 \leqslant y) $$